# Traversing a BST in an in-order fashion and storing the nodes in an array, but the output is not sorted?

Tags: python, binary-tree

I am traversing a `Binary Tree` in an `in-order manner` to determine if it is a `Binary Search Tree`. Here is my code:

```
class T:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def is_bst(node):  
    if not node:
        return 

    output = []
    
    is_bst(node.left)
    output.append(node.value) 
    is_bst(node.right)
    print(output)
```

[image]

For the above example, the `output = [1,3,2,9,7,5]`

But this is clearly not correct! - I would usually debug but I am not familiar with running trees/binary trees as inputs. Any idea where my code is going wrong???

---

Updated code:

```
class T:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

        
def inOrderTraversal(node,output): 
        if not node: 
            return None
        
        is_bst(node.left)
        output.append(node.value) 
        is_bst(node.right)
        return 
    
def is_bst(node):  
    
    output = []
    
    inOrderTraversal(node,output)
    
    print(output)
```

For the same example, the `output = [1,3,2,9,7,5]` is still wrong

Comment: Please do _not_ change essential parts of your question after it was replied. This way you make valid answers or comments look completely off topic. Additionally, you render your question useless for the community – future readers will not understand, what the actual problem was, so they'll be unable to learn from comments and answers given. If you want to share your progress, do not _replace_ your previous question but rather _add_ new info to it, or post a new question.

Comment: Understood Cia, I will create a new question or add to it in the future. Thanks

Comment: I have edited your question to show both the original code and the updated version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create your `output` inside the routine, so it's always empty. Then you add the current node's value but you print it at the end of the routine. The result is *postorder*, not inorder - each node is printed *after* both its subtrees.

Apart from the code structure your function has wrong name - you actually don't want it to answer whether the tree is BST, you just want it to return the contents:

```
def dump_tree_inorder(node, output):  
    if not node:
        return 
    
    dump_tree_inorder(node.left, output)
    output.append(node.value) 
    dump_tree_inorder(node.right, output)
```

Comment: Hi CiaPan; you mean I should create a helper function to run the recursion, and the output = [] would sit in the main function?

Comment: Yes - if you want to accumulate the whole list, that is the proper way.

Comment: Let me amend the code- I tried doing this but it results in the same output! - let me change it

Comment: Now the output is worse... []
[]
[1]
[]
[]
[3]
[2]
[]
[]
[]
[9]
[7]
[5]

Comment: @Patrick_Chong Please see the expanded answer :)

Comment: Thanks Cia- this is exactly what I thought it was- but it still gives the above output. Maybe it's the way the test cases are created